# cucumber webrat click on second delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

I've got a scenario which I want to select the 'Delete' link on the page for the second item in the table.  I've been looking at click_link_within or using within but it is not working correctly.

```
  Scenario: User deletes a staff member from the listing
    Given a staff exists with name: "Michael"
    And a staff exists with name: "Joe"
    And I am on the listing staff index page
    When I follow "Delete" for row containing "Joe"
    Then I should be on the listing staff index page
    And I should not see "Joe"
    And I should see "Michael"
```

Here is the step I'm trying to use:

```
When /^I follow "([^"]*)" for row containing "([^"]*)"$/ do |button, text|
  click_link_within "//*[.//td[contains(.,#{text})]]", button
end
```

And here is the listing code in haml:

```
%h1 Staff Listing 

%table
    %th Username
    %th Surname
    %th First Name

    - @staff.each do |staff|
        %tr
            %td= staff.username
            %td= staff.surname
            %td= staff.firstname
            %td= link_to "Edit", edit_staff_path(staff)
            %td= link_to "Delete", staff, :method => :delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating correct delete links rails uses javascript. So you get a DELETE request instead of GET which a normal link would produce. Since webrat doesn't handle javascript there is no way this can work. Check out Capybara as alternative to webrat or webrat with selenium.

Comment: I've got Capybara installed and I can click on a delete link, but not the second link.

Comment: Capybara installed is good, but you have to make sure you use it instead of webrat in cucumber (see: https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails after the install something like ruby script/generate cucumber --capybara). What do you mean you can click on a delete link, but not the second link? I don't understand.

Comment: What I mean is, I've got a list of staff and I have a delete link for each staff member in the list. I would like to get cucumber to click on the second delete link if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it! Which one is the 'second delete link'? As explained before: REST (principle implemented in Rails) defines the (HTTP) DELETE method for delete actions. A normal link gets you GET. Rails is smart enough to use javascript to do the DELETE for you! That means testing that needs JAVASCRIPT SUPPORT! Webrat/Cucumber == NO JS support. That means you have to switch to another brower driver for your tests. Pls install cucumber-rails as mentioned before, use capybara as a browser driver and try again.

Comment: I do have cucumber-rails installed and I'm using capybara. I can write a test in which there is one item in the listing with one 'delete' link on the page and this works. If however I have two or more items in my listing then I would have two or more links with the same name called 'delete'.

Comment: Sorry, now I get what you wanted to know in the first place. Your links should have unique ids, which you can use to refer to them. Otherwise check if `within("input:nth-child(#{pos.to_i}")` gets you somewhere.

Comment: I've tried this with no success: within("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5)") do click_link(button) end. I tried that same selector in css code and changed the background colour so that works.